# Unable to handle 404 error in axios with try and catch

Tags: api, promise, axios, http-status-code-404

I have been trying to build a weather app, but I have some trouble with verifying the http status in case a user inserts willingly a city name that doesn't exist or in case the user makes a typo inside the input field.

The only problem is that I can't find a way to insert the status !== 200 in the axios promise.

The 200 status works pretty fine, but the 404 doesn't. I am sure there is an error somewhere in the promise, but I can't manage to find the way out of it.

Moreover when I console log the error, it shows this message:

error in the console.log

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.E (xhr.js:66)
```

Javascript

```
try{            
            axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${api_key}`).then(
                
            async response => {
                
            let data = await response.data

            if (response.status !== 200) {
            
                throw new Error(response.status);
            
                } else {
            
            console.log(data)
            document.getElementById('hum').textContent = data.main.humidity;
            document.getElementById('feels-like').textContent = data.main.feels_like;
                }}
        )
        
        } catch(error) {
            if (response.status === 404) {
                console.log(`Err: ${error}`);
                throw err;
            }
                   
        
        };
```

Any suggestions is really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Your `try/catch` will not catch the rejection you throw in your `.then()` handler and will not catch any rejections that `axios` itself throws unless you `await` the axios call.

```
try {
    await axios.get(...).then(...)
} catch(e) {
    // now you can catch a rejection
}
```

Or, of course, you could switch to using `.catch()` instead.

---

Stylewise, it is not recommended to be mixing `try/catch`, `await` and `.then()` here.  You should either do:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.get(...);
    // process response here, including throw
} catch(e) {
    // here you can catch a rejection, either from axios
    // directly or from throwing in the processing
}
```

or:

```
axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The error was in the promise. Now it works.